# Tool tip for line chart using jqplot

Tags: jqplot

I want to add tool tip for my line chart using jqplot.
Can u please tell me how to add it..
Here is my code:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var plot2 = $.jqplot('chart1', [result], {
        seriesColors: [ "#000000", "#ff0000"],

          axes:{
               xaxis:{
                 renderer:$.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
               }
             },
 series:[{lineWidth:4, markerOptions:{style:'square'}}],   });  });
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code

```
highlighter: {
        show: true,
        sizeAdjust: 7.5
      }
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6Wgys/108/)

Answer (score 0):

You can start by Jqplot website :

Find examples [here](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/),

Again more examples [here](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/),

Especially about tooltip [here](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/cursor-highlighter.html),

Finally you can find documentations [here](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/usage-txt.html)

I think you can easily find other links doing a search on your favorite web search engine or on stackoverflow.com